# AWS market place AMI - Instance pricing when MP AMI is launched as an private Image

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, marketplace

If I launch a MarketPlace AMI, and take image(AMI) of that instance and relaunch it, will the application owner get the same charge ?

**i.e**

1. I launch an EC2 instance - pay 0.3$ /hour.
2. Now I take image of that instance and launch it again - pay same
   0.3$/hour

Coming to Marketplace,

1. I launch an Marketplace AMI in EC2 - pay 0.4$/hour (some amount will be given to marketplace AMI owner)  hence subscription is Active.
2. Now I take image of that marketplace as private AMI .
3. Launch that AMI in EC2 - how much will I pay ??? . Subscription may be active or inactive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will still pay the marketplace price, and the subscription will need to be active in order to launch and run instances from such an AMI.

Creating your own an AMI from an instance launched from a marketplace AMI preserves the necessary metadata in the new AMI so that the EC2 infrastructure as well as the licensed software running in any new instances is able to detect and verify that the new instance is being correctly billed.  For obvious reasons, this metadata isn't editable.

> To copy a shared AMI with a `billingProduct` code, launch an EC2 instance in your account using the shared AMI and then create an AMI from the instance.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/CopyingAMIs.html

The "shared AMI" in this case would refer to the original marketplace AMI. Any AMI you create with this mechanism will be your own private AMI -- it can't be subsequently shared.

Comment: Really thanks for the info . The private image which I took from an Marketplace AMI is not working after I cancelled my subscription . It was fine... 

If I am a seller then can I set a permission to take image of our running AMI and launch it in subscriber account without another subscription activation ? Cuz I have scenario where I have to deliver an image of subscribed AMI with resource usage price charging alone , in that case what shall I do ?

Comment: No, marketplace doesn't work that way.  The cost model is fixed and every customer pays the same rate for the same deployment.